# How to refactor if statement using De Morgans law java

Tags: java, if-statement, demorgans-law

So I have a very unreadable if statement and someone suggested me to look at De Morgans law and refactor it so it would be more clean and readable. I got the idea how to do it with simple and short statements but I really do not know how to refactor my code. Note that first two are objects! Thanks for your help!

```
if (!userTemplate.getFromAccount().equals(document.getDetails())
    && !userTemplate.getBenAccount().equals(document.getFromAccount())
    && !userTemplate.getDetails().equals(document.getBenAccount())
    && !userTemplate.getBenType().equals(document.getBenType())
    && !userTemplate.getAmount().equals(document.getCreditAmount()))
```

Comment: Did you look up [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering)?

Comment: Yes, I'm going through the theoretical part! But not sure how to implement it in this case!

Comment: Whoever told you that its unclean and unreadable, aint that good. I find this very easy to read and to understand. Yes its a long `IF`, but De Morgans law wont change that

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia, De Morgans law can be explained in simple terms as

> not (A or B) = not A and not B;
>
> not (A and B) = not A or not B

So your current `if` statement

```
if (!userTemplate.getFromAccount().equals(document.getDetails())
                    && !userTemplate.getBenAccount().equals(document.getFromAccount())
                    && !userTemplate.getDetails().equals(document.getBenAccount())
                    && !userTemplate.getBenType().equals(document.getBenType())
                    && !userTemplate.getAmount().equals(document.getCreditAmount()))
```

Can be refactored as

```
if (!(userTemplate.getFromAccount().equals(document.getDetails())
                    || userTemplate.getBenAccount().equals(document.getFromAccount())
                    || userTemplate.getDetails().equals(document.getBenAccount())
                    || userTemplate.getBenType().equals(document.getBenType())
                    || userTemplate.getAmount().equals(document.getCreditAmount())))
```

Comment: Somehow I find the refactored code way harder to understand than the actual code

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, De Morgans law doesn't necessarily improve the readability of a boolean expression. The rule just states how a boolean expression can be expressed in different form.

Comment: Yeah, commented it mostly because of the "more clean and readable" part in the question

Comment: @VHS Thanks for your help! I will propose both examples! I was thinking about making a separate method for this and then implement it! Maybe that way it will be more clean!

Comment: Yeah boolean algebra transformations don't necessarily make more readable code. Even though, the number of negations is reduced. The first example should read "if all the pairs differ" while the second is "if not even a single pair is equal"

Answer (score 1):

It would also be a good idea to extract all these conditions into booleans, would make the `if` more readable too.

```
boolean fromAccountCondition = userTemplate.getFromAccount().equals(document.getDetails());
boolean benAccountcondition = userTemplate.getBenAccount().equals(document.getFromAccount());
boolean detailsCondition = userTemplate.getDetails().equals(document.getBenAccount());
boolean benTypeCondition = userTemplate.getBenType().equals(document.getBenType());
boolean amountCondition = userTemplate.getAmount().equals(document.getCreditAmount()))
```

Then

```
if (!(fromAccountCondition || benAccountcondition 
      || detailsCondition || benTypeCondition || amountCondition)) {
  ...
}
```

**NOTE:** I would actually prefer to put the negation in the booleans themselves, ie:

```
boolean fromAccountCondition = !userTemplate.getFromAccount().equals(document.getDetails());
boolean benAccountcondition = !userTemplate.getBenAccount().equals(document.getFromAccount());
boolean detailsCondition = !userTemplate.getDetails().equals(document.getBenAccount());
boolean benTypeCondition = !userTemplate.getBenType().equals(document.getBenType());
boolean amountCondition = !userTemplate.getAmount().equals(document.getCreditAmount()))
```

Then

```
if (fromAccountCondition && benAccountcondition 
    && detailsCondition && benTypeCondition && amountCondition)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This would be my approach as well.  Sometimes it takes writing _more_ code to improve readability.  And I'm sure that knowing the actual business cases behind the code would lead to much more meaningful boolean variable names.

Comment: agreed, naming variables is very important

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but your if-statement says `!A*!B*!C*!D` which equals `!(A+B+C+D)`.

Answer (score 0):

De Morgan's law says (written in Java language):

```
(!A && !B && !C && ...)  ==  !(A || B || C || ...)
```

Therefore you can rewrite your code (I shorten the lengthy expressions for clarity):

```
if (!A && !B && !C && !D && !E)
```

to

```
if (!(A || B || C || D || E))
```